# Android Studio Java - Convert 3gp file to wav without ffmpeg

Tags: java, android-studio, wav, audio-recording, converters

I'm writing an `Android Studio` project in `Java` that records audio, then sends it to a `flask server` to extract its musical notes.

Since I found `MediaRecorder` easier to use and more friendly than the other solutions, I use it to record the audio. However, it doesn't support`wav` format. (The different output formats that are supported are `MPEG_4 | WEBM | THREE_GPP | AAC_ADTS | AMR_NB | AMR_WB | MPEG_2_TS | OGG` and I currently use `3gp` (THREE_GPP)).

Because my flask server accepts `wav` files only, my goal is to convert the recorded file (can be any of the supported formats above) to `wav` format. I've already tried to use the `ffmpeg` library, as I found this solution on this website, but it didn't let me execute `ffmpeg commands` due to permission limits.

So my final question is, how can I convert the recorded audio file to `wav` format using `Java` and without executing any shell commands?

If there is a better way to accomplish my goals, such as fix the permission error I have had or any other solution, I would love to hear that as well.

Comment: Is `android.media.AudioRecord` not a good option for recording? It supports WAV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an alternative to record `wav` files in android studio.

It is a class called `WavAudioRecorder` I found on github.

Credit: https://github.com/roman10/roman10-android-tutorial/blob/master/AndroidWaveRecorder/src/roman10/tutorial/androidwaverecorder/WavAudioRecorder.java